# Saving editable data in Rails 3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, heroku, persistence

My rails app allows users to edit a certain json file through the browser. This data file is saved in `app/assets/data/thefile.json` (the site is only used internally)

I tested the front-end locally and it worked fine, the data gets updated and saved. Then I pushed the code to Heroku and tested it there as well. It worked. However after about 1 day when I go back to the site, I realized that the data has reverted to its original state before it was edited.

This happened numerous times and I'm not so sure why it happened. Maybe because Heroku does not allow files in the `app` folder to be edited?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably has something to do with the fact that Heroku has a [read only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem).

There's also a note here on the [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral_filesystem)

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.**

Comment: Where should I store the file then?

Comment: You can't store it on the heroku file system period. If it's something dynamic that changes and you need to keep track of it then the database is an option.

Comment: Yep, don't use heroku for uploading stuff to. For that most people use something like Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks @Dty, the link was very helpful (I just read the Amazon S3 part in the link you provided so I deleted my question).